# Save data from grid using Dapper.net and ServiceStack.OrmLite

Tags: vb.net, servicestack, dapper

I'm using datagridview for CRUD operations.

Earlier when I used **ADO.net** and later when I moved to **EF** i successfully was committing every command that I wanted. Insert, update or delete.

Suppose i want to update first row, or four row and eleven row, and what if i delete a second, and also what if i need to add a new row. All that in same time using **datagridview**.

Then after all this modification i just need to call **DA.Update(DS)** or in EF **SaveChanges** and all my data will be saved. In first two scenario i can do exactly that!

Example for first two: ADO.NET AND EF6

I have done this in the following way :

1. ADO.NET:

   ```
       Dim command As New SqlCommand

       command = New SqlCommand(query, conn)
       command.CommandTimeout = 200
       ds = New DataSet
       SQLDA = New SqlDataAdapter(command)


       SQLDA.Fill(ds)
       Dim cb As New SqlCommandBuilder(SQLDA)
       Dim bs As New BindingSource
       bs .DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
       DGV.DataSource = bs 

       button_clik
     SQLDA.UPDATE(ds)    'save all changes i have made
   ```
2. EF

   ```
           db = New _Context

           db.tPROMs.Load()

           Dim b = db.tPROMs.Local.ToBindingList

           b.AllowEdit = True
           b.AllowNew = True
           b.AllowRemove = True

           Dim bs As New BindingSource
           bs.DataSource = b
           DGV.DataSource = bs 

           button_clik
           db.SaveChanges()   'save all changes i have made
   ```

Now how can i save data directly from the grid using **DAPPER.NET** or **ServiceStack.OrmLite**

So far I have done this over ADO.NET and later with EF6. But for better performance now I want to do with Dapper.net or ServiceStack.OrmLite.

3. **DAPPER.NET**

   ```
           ???????
   ```
4. **ServiceStack.OrmLite**

   ```
           ???????
   ```

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29265396/save-data-from-grid-using-dapper-net-and-servicestack-ormlite/29266257#29266257)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having hard time following your code but dapper syntax for insert should be like this:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("YourConnString"))
{
    return conn.Execute(query, instaceToInsert);
}
```

Dapper will automatically map the properties in your model to fields in your query...

So for example if you insert query is:

```
INSERT INTO Users (LastName, FirstName) VALUES (@LastName, @FirstName)
```

then your model needs to be something like:

```
public class User
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

And then replace instanceToInsert with instance of user...

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("YourConnString"))
{
    return conn.Execute(query, new User {LastName = "John", FirstName = "Doe"});
}
```

Here is the VB.NET version:

```
Using conn = New SqlConnection("YourConnString")
    Return conn.Execute(query, instaceToInsert)
End Using

Public Class User
    Public Property LastName() As String
    Public Property FirstName() As String
End Class

Using conn = New SqlConnection("YourConnString")
   Return conn.Execute(query, New User() With { .LastName = "John", .FirstName = "Doe"})
End Using
```

Comment: his code is in VB.NET and i don't think that the params (list, array, whatever) will successfully map with the execute query...

Comment: @stefankmitph Param object will map regardless of language... otherwise dapper would be useless...

Comment: that's true, mate. but how about this line `AddWithValue("@" & i, param(i))`. how can a param `@0, @1, @2` map with dapper?

Comment: He can use anonymous object then: new { p1 = "John", p2 = "Doe" } and then his parameters would be @p1, etc.... If he wants the parameter names to be numbers only then tough luck...

Comment: @Marko  This is not solution. What if i want to update one row, or four row and eleven row, and what if i delete a second, and also what if i need to add a new row. Then after this modification i need to call **SaveChanges**. In first two scenario i can do exactly that!

Comment: Then you are missing the point of Dapper. Dapper is not like Entity Framework or NHibernate. It is micro ORM, it does not persist context state like a full blown ORMs do... That is the trade off, if you want speed you use Dapper but you lose the convenience of changing states of your objects and then persisting them in one line with SaveChanges call. There is no one punch solution here. I suggest you read this post from Jimmy Bogard - https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/07/20/choosing-an-orm-strategy/

Comment: @dejan as Marko says: this is largely the difference between a micro-ORM and a full ORM. Dapper does not do change tracking for you - that is one of the heavy features that it simply doesn't even attempt to provide. Basically: you need a different approach with the different tools. I would say this doesn't make either "better" or "worse" - just different

Comment: @Marko just edit your answer just like your comment. I already accept.